# Difficulties to save on a mongodb collection information from a Form

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create an app using MEAN stack. I am using mongoose for the schema for my mongodb database. On one collection, which contains String, Number and Date fields, I am having errors when trying to save into the database. Part of the information input by the use is numbers and dates. This is giving me an error and I notice that I never saves it. Question: after I capture the information in the form, do I have to convert from String to Number and from String to Date? If so, I have tried to convert Date.parse to convert String to Date and parseInt to cover from string to number, as follow:

```
    app.post('/api/show/post', authCheck, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Entrada a post");
    console.log(req.body);

    var ciaID = "     ";
    req.body.moveid = Date.parse(req.body.movein);
    req.body.open = Date.parse(req.body.open);
    req.body.close = Date.parse(req.body.close);

    req.body.number = parseInt(req.body.number);
    req.body.estimateamount = parseInt(req.body.estimateamount);
    req.body.balancedue = parseInt(req.body.balancedue);

    mongoose.model('company').findOne({name: "test company"},          function(err,doc){ 
        var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
            ciaID = new ObjectID(doc._id);  
    }); 

    var show = new Show(req.body);


    show.created_at = Date();
    show.updated_at = Date();
    show.created_by = "username";
    show.updated_by = "username"; 

    show.save(function(err, doc){

        if (err) {
        console.log(" the program all gets in here");   
           return err
        }
        else {

            res.status(201).json(doc);         
        }               
    });
});
```

I also tried Not to convert any of these values and on neither case it worked. I have other collections, which only contains String fields and I don't have any problem with it.

I will appreciate any advice,

Thank you in advance

Comment: As i think, you may have problem on saving date, because mongodb accepts ISO date format, so try this var                                                             crtDate = new Date();
var dateToSave = crtDate.toISOString();

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, what I can see here is that you suggest to change the fields in the database from Date to String. am I correct?

Comment: sitll if u have a issue in saving dat, post your model & your final show object which u are going to save.

Comment: Thank you for making follow up. Due to your last post, I found the problem. There is a field that is defined on mongodb and mongoose as Date, and was being used wrong in the form. mongoose won't let me save that to keep integrity. Silly mistake, really sorry.Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you rroxysam for making follow up. Due to your last post, I found the problem. There is a field that is defined on mongodb and mongoose as Date, and was being used wrong in the form. mongoose won't let me save that to keep integrity. Silly mistake, really sorry.Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check:

```
req.body.moveid = new Date(req.body.movein);
req.body.open = new Date(req.body.open);
req.body.close = new Date(req.body.close);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried but it didn't work